# nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 128; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, xml, spring

**i added xsi:schemaLocation correctly but it is showing error**

```
<beans xmlsn="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean   id="welcomebean"    class="com.sathya.beans.WelcomeBean">
    <property name="message"    value="welcome to Spring"></property>   
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<beans xmlsn="...">` to `<beans xmlns="...">`.

Comment: now error is coming  like this org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'WelcomeBean' available  package com.sathya.beans;
this is my WelcomeBean class
public class WelcomeBean 
{
 private String message;
 
 public void setMessage(String message)
 {
  this.message=message;
 }
 public void showMessage()
 {
  System.out.println("Message="+message);
 }
}